# Filtering a Range based on criteria using a UDF

Tags: excel, function, vba

I tried creating a UDF to filter a range based on one or more criteria. The reason I used a `Function` and not a `Sub` is that I wanted to be able to use it directly from the worksheet, just by selecting the criteria and fields to be filtered.

This is what I got:

```
Function FilterTable(Criteria As Range, Table As Range, Column As 
Integer)
Dim cell As Range
Dim arrList() As String, lngCnt As Long
Application.Volatile
lngCnt = 0
For Each cell In Criteria.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim Preserve arrList(lngCnt)
    arrList(lngCnt) = cell.Text
    lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
Next
With ActiveSheet
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    Table.AutoFilter Field:=Column, Criteria1:=arrList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End Function
```

The issues I'm having with this are:

1- While the UDF is on a cell, I can't undo the filter (that's somewhat expected, since the UDF reapplies the filter whenever I remove it) is there a way to remove this "limitation"? Now I'm getting by using an IF formula in a cell, but I'd like to know if there's a way for the UDF to work only once.

2- If there's a previous filtered range in the sheet, that range is filtered instead (.ShowAllData isn't working properly);

3- Sometimes, if I remove the UDF and apply a filter to another range, the previous UDF-filtered range becomes hidden (e.g. the UDF filter would hide lines 3~5, after applying a filter to another range, those lines will still be hidden, and only appear again after unhiding in the context menu).

So, anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the `Function` to a `Sub` since it's not actually a function and does not return any values. Functions have limitations that Subs do not. This may solve all your problems.

Comment: Also, `Specialcells` doesn't work properly in a UDF.

Comment: This is not a `Function` as mentioned above. A UDF should have a return value and can not alter any cells, filters, etc. etc.